# AVAudioRecorder Small Memory Leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I recently discovered a leak in my application.  I commented all the code out and got rid of the comments step by step.  It all led to the AVAudioRecorder.

ViewController.h:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
}
```

ViewController.m:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];

NSError *error;

recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

if (recorder) {
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder record];
}
```

[image: Memory Leak]

Sorry for the small picture.  The memory leak is only 16 bytes and I can't trace it back to the code because it doesn't allow me to so I just used the commenting strategy.  `[recorder stop];` is used whenever exiting the view controller.

**Any Ideas?**

Comment: Are you running this on the device or trying to run it in a simulator?

Comment: see my response below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with NSURL leaking memory in the simulator.

https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=nsurl%20simulator%20leak